# gcc unix environmental variable

Tags: unix, cygwin

```
src="binds.c engine.c console.c"
echo $src
gcc $src
```

---

The batch file above works with the echo but the gcc fails. If I type
`gcc $src`  at the command line, that works.  So it seems that gcc doesn't get environment local variables within a batch file?

Using CYGWIN.

Comment: Did you `export` the variable?

Comment: export? It's in the same script, for what I can tell by the question.

Comment: What's the output of the "batch file" when you run it?

Comment: This is not a batch file. This is a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cygwin, then you're running on Windows in a Unix-emulation.  A pretty good one, but still an emulation.  However, you are also probably using `bash` as your shell, which is good (and if by any chance you're using Korn shell, what I say below applies equally, and if you're using `/bin/sh`, that is effectively a subset of `bash` and what I say applies to that, too).

Note that you can define variables in your shell that are not in the shell's environment.  This distinction is important when it comes to running other scripts.

```
src="binds.c engine.c console.c"
```

This creates a non-environment variable called `src`.  You can now use this at the command line:

```
echo $src
gcc -c $src
```

The `echo` command will list the three names, and GCC will be run and will attempt to compile all three source files.  However, if you run the `env` command, you will not see `src` in the environment.  On the other hand, if you run the `set` command, you will see `src`.

```
env    # No arguments - list the environment variables that are exported
set    # No arguments - lists variables, exported and non-exported
```

Now suppose that you have (or create) a script called `compile` in the current directory that contains:

```
gcc -c $src
```

The script should be executable (`chmod +x compile`).  If you run:

```
./compile
```

the script does not see the variable `$src` because it is not exported, so you get an error about no file names specified from GCC.  Funnily enough, if you run either of these:

```
. ./compile
source ./compile
```

then the compilation occurs as you wanted.  That's because instead of starting a sub-shell to execute the script, the current shell reads the script, and the variable `src` is defined.

If you now export `src`, it becomes available to sub-shells and other programs:

```
export src     # Sufficient given the initial assignment
export src="binds.c engine.c console.c" # Set and export; not portable to Bourne shell
```

Now if you run `env`, you will see `src` listed.  And now if you run `./compile`, it will have a variable `src` in its environment, so the compilation will occur as expected.

So, the key points are:

- Not all shell variables are environment variables.
- To make a variable into an environment variable, you must `export` it explicitly.

There are some other tricks that can be pulled with environment variables, but they are not yet germane to your situation and would more likely confuse than help.  (*I'm thinking of `set -k` and `var=value cmd arg1 ...` for those who know.*)

Comment: Wow, a shell problem, I am running cygwin in windows. Thanks a bunch, you have cleared a mystery.